# GIDSignIn iOS 9

Tags: ios9, gidsignin

Using Googles SignIn in my AppDelegate I have

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
  openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
        sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
        annotation: annotation)
}
```

But that function is deprecated as of iOS 9 for

```
application:openURL:options:
```

How to return

> GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
>               sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
>               annotation: annotation)

Using the new function for iOS 9?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use this:

```
//Google Login
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as! String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
}

//for IOS 8    
@available(iOS, introduced=8.0, deprecated=9.0)
func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication!, annotation: annotation)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just for reference, if using Objective-C, the method implementation is:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                               sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                      annotation:annotation];
}
```

If on iOS 9, it would be recommended to also implement the new format:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(nonnull NSURL *)url options:(nonnull NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options {
    return [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                               sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                      annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
}
```